extend nswag generated typescript classes
I am working with Nswag to generate typescript clients for our vue app. It is creating a ServiceProxyBase that all the generated types extend. It also is generating a constructor that accepts the baseurl and axios instance. I have not found a way to remove this from the constructor so that it can use my axios (import { axiosInst } from "@/plugins/axios";). So what I would like is to generate a new class that accepts just a componentname which will used in the 2 transform functions.
I want to enforce the usage of our axiosInst and not have them set the baseurl. Also, based on my reading you should use a single axios instance not create a new one for each usage. Is my understanding of this incorrect? If so, I would still like to generate the Client for other possible ideas.

// service.base.ts
import type { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios"; // ignore

class ServiceProxyBase {
  component: string;

  constructor(component: string) {
    this.component = component;
  }

  public transformOptions(options: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) {
    console.log("HTTP call, options: " + JSON.stringify(options));
    return Promise.resolve(options);
  }

  public transformResult(
    url: string,
    response: AxiosResponse,
    processor: (response: AxiosResponse) => any
  ) {
    console.log("HTTP response, url: " + url);
    console.log("HTTP response, status: " + response.status);
    console.log("HTTP response, data: " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
    const transformedData = processor(response);
    return transformedData;
  }
}

// service-proxy.ts (trimmed)
export class TestServiceProxy extends ServiceProxyBase {
    // .. generated ..

    constructor(configuration: string, baseUrl?: string, instance?: AxiosInstance) {

        super(configuration);

        this.instance = instance || axios.create();

        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ?? "";

    }

    // .. generated methods ..
}

// generated-clients that I want
import { axiosInst } from "@/plugins/axios";
import { * } from "./service-proxies";

export class TestClient extends TestServiceProxy {
  constructor(componentName: string) {
    super(componentName, undefined, axiosInst);
  }
}

nswag.json
{
  "runtime": "Default",
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "url": "<host>swagger/v1/swagger.json",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "{controller}ServiceProxy",
      "typeScriptVersion": 4.3,
      "clientBaseClass": "ServiceProxyBase",
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": true,
      "useTransformResultMethod": true,
      "typeStyle": "Class",
      "enumStyle": "Enum",
      "extensionCode": "src/services/service.base.ts",
      "output": "src/services/service-proxies.ts",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}

